# Call a parent's method from child, similar to calling "super" (C++)

Tags: c++, inheritance

Is it possible to "reuse" a parent method in a child method and add functionality, just like with the super operator in Java?

```
parent.method(int a){
  a++;
}

child.method(int a /*would be nice w/out*/){
  printf("%d",a);
}
```

I know that this is probably quite a basic question, sorry about that.

I know I can just copy/paste the method to the child class and add the functionality there, by overloading; I'm looking for a more convenient way though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [__super](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94dw1w7x%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to do this, but it is a Microsoft extension.

```
void CChild::function( int nParam )
{
    __super::function( nParam );
}
```

Alternatively you can explicitly call the base implementation from the derived class:

```
void CChild::function( int nParam )
{
    CParent::function( nParam );
}
```

Comment: `__super` will not work if there is multiple inheritance, right? At any rate, `CParent::function` approach is superior, even though Microsoft has provided a *super* keyword, which is ironically not *superior*. ;-)

Comment: @Nawaz Agreed, if nothing else it is a standard way of doing it. ;-)

Comment: You could use `typedef CParent super;` and then `super::function(nParam);`

Answer (score 6):

You can invoke the parent member function in a child member function by qualifing the member function name with the name of the parent class:

```
void child::method()
{
    parent::method();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is no `super` keyword, but you just give the name of the parent class instead.

```
int child::method(int a ){ 
  // call base class
  int i = parent::method(a);
  printf("%d",a); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
parent.method(int a){
  a++;
}

child::method(int a /*would be nice w/out*/){
  printf("%d",a);
  parent::method(a);
}
```